# Converting a date and time string in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an XML object being returned, and inside is a date and time code that looks like this,

```
[Date] => 20120229
[Time] => 032400
```

How can I convert those into a date and time like,  02-29-1012 and 03:24:00 ?

Thank you.

Comment: will they always be in that exact format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume Date is in $date and time in $Time.

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $date.$time);
echo $d->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Worked great  Thanks,   is there anyway to separate the date and time with a comma?

Comment: @thatryan Just replace the space with a comma.  Or, if you mean in the input, just change the format to Ymd,His and do $date . ',' . $time.

Answer (score 1):

Use strtome like this:

```
$dt = date('m-d-Y h:i:s', strtotime($d . ' ' . $t));
```

**TEST:**

```
echo date('m-d-Y h:i:s', strtotime('20120229 032400')) . "\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
02-29-2012 03:24:00
```

Comment: The Y-m-d here should be m-d-Y and the h should be an H or you should add an A at the end of the date function format like 'Y-m-d H:i:s' (24 hour time) or 'Y-m-d h:i:s A' (12 hour time with a trailing AM or PM)

Comment: Tried this method using the variables and it keeps outputting the year as 1969 and time as 04:00                                          echo date('m-d-Y h:i:s A', strtotime($activity[$i]->Date $activity[$i]->Time)) . "\n";